# Change opacity on NSTextAttachment's image

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I seem to have an issue with changing the transparency with an `NSTextAttachment`'s image in an `NSAttributedString`.

I have a string that I would like to fade in and out, but it seems that the images attached to the string do not fade out along with the text.

I have tried setting both the `NSBackgroundColorAttributeName` and `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` attribute to the desired alpha, but this does not work.

I am also not seeing an alpha or opacity property with `NSTextAttachment`,  so the only option I am seeing is attaching a new `UIImage` with the corrected alpha,  but this approach is going to be a last resort.

I am hoping somebody out there has a method for changing the alpha without me having to do that.

Either Objective-C or Swift code works for me.

Comment: Just to clarify. Do you need to only change the alpha of the `NSTextAttachment` image but not the rest of the string?

Comment: the rest of the string is already changing,  it is the NSTextAttachment that stays a solid color

Comment: If this is being displayed in a `UILabel` or other `UIView` subclass, is changing the `alpha` working? It works for me.

Comment: Unfortunately I have different alpha across the various text, the entire string is not consistently the same alpha.

Comment: Better understanding of the effect,  Note, the bug I am facing is not in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SIYN2JX4tFs

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, here is what I am doing:

````
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics
extension UIImage
{
    /// copyWithAlpha: Creates a copy of a UIImage with the new alpha
    /// - Parameter alpha: Alpha value to set new image to. Between (0.0 - 1.0)
    /// - Returns: UIImage
    ///```swift
    ///   let copyImage = originalImage.copyWithAlpha(1.0)
    func copyWithAlpha(alpha:CGFloat) -> UIImage
    {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, false, self.scale);
        drawAtPoint(CGPointZero,blendMode:.Normal, alpha:alpha);
        let alphaImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return alphaImage;
    }
}
````

This method is free for anybody to use.  However, I am not happy about this method, because it requires me to keep a copy of the original `UIImage`, and apply the alpha every time to the original,  I can't keep reapplying this to the `UIImage` that gets returned.